# Error in df % > % mutate(price_scal = scale(price), hd_scal = scale(hd), : could not find function "% > %"

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr

I want to practice this tutorial https://www.guru99.com/r-k-means-clustering.html
but I stuck with  this code

```
rescale_df <- df % > %
 mutate(price_scal = scale(price),
     hd_scal = scale(hd),
     ram_scal = scale(ram),
     screen_scal = scale(screen),
     ads_scal = scale(ads),
     trend_scal = scale(trend)) % > %
 select(-c(price, speed, hd, ram, screen, ads, trend))

Error in df % > % mutate(price_scal = scale(price), hd_scal = scale(hd),  : 
  could not find function "% > %"
```

Comment: can you load the package `library(dplyr)`. Not clear whether you have spaces or not.  It should be `%>%`  and not `% > %`

Comment: In R, many operators can deal with arbitrary spaces *around* them, such as `+` and `/`; however, functions and "special" operators need to be complete without spaces within them. Just like you would not expect to be able to do `read   .   csv("file.csv")`, you cannot do `%   in   %` or `%   >   %`.

Comment: @r2evans it happens when they. are copying code directly from a pdf or other sources which changes the format.  Sometimes, the quotes are also fancy quotes and iif we don't pay that much attention to the characters, it can take some time to debug